# Struggling with Vue.js component integration in Laravel's app.blade.php. It's not working, unlike ExampleComponent. Any quick fixes?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, components

I'm experiencing an issue with my Laravel 10 project integrated with Vue.js 3. When I attempt to use a Vue.js component within Laravel, it doesn't seem to work, unlike the ExampleComponent which functions correctly.

I have a layout.vue file:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <menu></menu>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  // Other component options
};
</script>
```

In my app.js:

```
import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';

import Menu from './components/header/Menu.vue';
import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';
import Layout from "./layouts/layout.vue";
import Index from "./pages/index.vue";

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Index },
  ]
});

const app = createApp(Layout);
app.component('menu', Menu);
app.component('example-component', ExampleComponent);
app.component("layout-component", Layout);
app.use(router);
app.mount('#app');
```

And this is my index.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    This is my content
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Index'
}
</script>
```

In my app.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <!-- Head section... -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <layout-component></layout-component>
        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>

    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```